# iOS Add links while creating PDF

Tags: ios, pdf, hyperlink, pdf-generation

I am creating a PDF using UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile in iOS, where I want to add URL links to other pages as well as other websites. Below is the code : here pdfObj is a custom class which draws text to PDF. After Succesfull creation of PDF nothing happens if I clicks the area for "GO to Chapter1" and "GO to URL"

```
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(documentDirectoryFilename, CGRectZero, nil);
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();

//Page 1
UIGraphicsAddPDFContextDestinationAtPoint(@"Chapter1", CGPointMake(0, 0));
//other draw pdf data....

//Page 2
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
//other draw pdf data....
[pdfObj addHeaderText:@"Go to Chapter 1" atFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 44)];
UIGraphicsSetPDFContextDestinationForRect(@"Chapter1", CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 44));

[pdfObj addHeaderText:@"Go to URL" atFrame:CGRectMake(550, 550, 200, 44)];
UIGraphicsSetPDFContextURLForRect([NSURL urlWithString:@"http://www.myURL.com"], CGRectMake(550, 550, 200, 44));

UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

Please let me know what mistake I am making here

Comment: The above code works perfectly well just that the y coordinates are inverted for core graphics

Answer (score 2):

check the answer to this question it works:[Embed hyperlink in PDF using Core Graphics on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14748204/embed-hyperlink-in-pdf-using-core-graphics-on-ios)

```
- (void) drawTextLink:(NSString *) text inFrame:(CGRect) frameRect 
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGAffineTransform ctm = CGContextGetCTM(context);

    // Translate the origin to the bottom left.
    // Notice that 842 is the size of the PDF page. 
    CGAffineTransformTranslate(ctm, 0.0, 842);

    // Flip the handedness of the coordinate system back to right handed.
    CGAffineTransformScale(ctm, 1.0, -1.0);

    // Convert the update rectangle to the new coordiante system.
    CGRect xformRect = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(frameRect, ctm);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:text];        
    UIGraphicsSetPDFContextURLForRect( url, xformRect );

    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    NSDictionary *attributesDict;
    NSMutableAttributedString *attString;

    NSNumber *underline = [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUnderlineStyleSingle];
    attributesDict = @{NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : underline, NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blueColor]};
    attString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:url.absoluteString attributes:attributesDict];

    [attString drawInRect:frameRect];

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```