# Adding website link in PDF file not working

Tags: ios, swift, pdf

I am generating PDF file and add link in footer of PDF file. It shows string as highlighted but it is not redirecting to website.

I'm using Swift 3. Here is my code:

```
class CustomPrintPageRenderer: UIPrintPageRenderer {

 //some code here

 override func drawFooterForPage(at pageIndex: Int, in footerRect: CGRect)  {

    let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)

    let textAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName:font, NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.darkGray]
    let text = NSAttributedString(string: "This is a computer generated document, ", attributes: textAttributes)

    let website = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: "Click here to visit website.")
    website.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: NSURL.init(string: "www.google.com")!, range: NSMakeRange(0, website.length))

    let footerContent = NSMutableAttributedString()

    footerContent.append(text)
    footerContent.append(website)

    let textSize = getTextSize(text: footerContent.string, font: font)
    let centerX = footerRect.size.width/2 - textSize.width/2
    let centerY = footerRect.origin.y + 10
    footerContent.draw(at: CGPoint(x: centerX, y: centerY))
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you change your URL to https://www.google.com? Maybe it's doubt to NSAppTransportSecurity reason... https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33

Comment: I have changed it to google.com but it is not working. I am generating and sending PDF through mail and opening PDF in mail. So there shouldn't be a problem of NSAppTransportSecurity.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22326745/ios-add-links-while-creating-pdf

Comment: @SaadChaudhry it is not working
 
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    let ctm = context!.ctm
    
    // Notice that 842 is the size of the PDF page.
    ctm.translatedBy(x: 0.0, y: 842)
    
    // Flip the handedness of the coordinate system back to right handed.
    ctm.scaledBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0);
   
    let xformRect = footerRect.applying(ctm);
    
    let url = URL.init(string: "google.com")
    UIGraphicsSetPDFContextURLForRect( url!, xformRect)
    context!.saveGState()

// here is my attributed string code

context!.restoreGState()